# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Word for typing an arrow symbol?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, characters, typing, symbols

You often see people using `->` as an arrow, but I hate how it looks. I always use the `→` symbol but to do so I have to `insert > symbol`, which is annoying.

Is there any way (shortcut) to insert this symbol in Word (2013)?

Comment: i've always found it autocorrects if you do `--><SPACE>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the Numpad (the other numbers won't work!).

```
↑   ALT+24  Upwards arrow
↓   ALT+25  Downwards arrow
→   ALT+26  Rightwards arrow
←   ALT+27  Leftwards arrow
↔   ALT+29  Left right arrow
▲   ALT+30  Upwards filled arrow
▼   ALT+31  Downwards filled arrow
►   ALT+16  Rightwards filled arrow
◄   ALT+17  Leftwards filled arrow
```

Answer (score 12):

People who type `->` probably don't know that if you type `-->` you get the default arrow in Word.

If you actually want `-->` to be shown in Word, you can type `-->` and press backspace, which will undo the automatical conversion to the arrow image.

Comment: This is a better solution for word than the answer from Fenixp. Because the other answer does not work for me in Word.

Answer (score 8):

You could try just using alt codes of these characters:

- <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>26</kbd> for →
- <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>27</kbd> for ←

Comment: Of course it's not [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), where char(27) is Escape. Also ASCII is only 7 bit, so Alt-128 or above wouldn't work if it was ASCII.

Comment: But we get your intent - this helped me, so plus 1!!

Comment: @DaveBoltman Thank you for correction on otherwise fairly irrelevant answer (seeing the accepted one). I always feel like my past self is a very dumb person.

Comment: I came here looking for left and right arrows, so your answer was 100% relevant to me - thank you! Many people today think that any character codes mean ASCII, so it's a common mistake. (For the printable characters (i.e. codes 32 to 127) and two or three others, they are the same, but ASCII codes outside of that are pretty much unused today.)

Comment: no need to use left Alt, right Alt would behave just like the left one, except on keyboard layouts that map the right Alt to AltGr

Answer (score 4):

This is probably only relevant in a few cases, but I'll still write it. It did help me. It's a three-step method that can be performed without leaving the keyboard.

1. Both in OneNote 2013 and Word 2013, the equation mode can be started with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>
2. In there, you can write arrows with a code word like `\rightarrow`, `\leftarrow` or `\uparrow`. Pressing space after typing the code word automatically transforms it into the desired arrow.
3. Leave the equation mode again with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>.

Comment: you don't need to enter equation mode if you [enabled `Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions`](https://superuser.com/a/1324610/241386)

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do that

## 1. AutoCorrect

By default `-->` will be changed to a *light right-pointed arrow*. Similarly `==>` will be a *heavy right-pointed arrow*. There are also other types of arrows and you can also **insert your own ones** so you don't need any shortcuts

[image: AutoCorrect arrows]

Of course this needs AutoCorrect to be turned on. If it was turned off, you need to turn it on again by selecting *File > Word Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options... > Replace text as you type*

A downside of this is that many of the arrows are from the [private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) like U+F0E0 U+F0E8, therefore you can't copy them around to other applications easily, but of course if you only use them in Word then it'll be fine

## 2. Math AutoCorrect

With this feature `->` will be converted into → by default without doubling the hyphen.

There are even more types of arrows, including curved ones and diagonal ones like `\asmash \hsmash \hsphantom \mapsto \lrhar \searrow \swarrow`...

This needs *Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions* to be turned on beside the normal AutoCorrect.

[image][image]

## 3. MS Word's hex input

Just type the codepoint in hex (with or without `U+`) and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, Word will do the conversion for you. This works for **any** Unicode characters

For example `↗` is U+2197 so just type `2197` then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
However sometimes you need to type `2` followed by U+0197 (i.e. **2Ɨ**) then you must type `2U+197` or `2U+0197` then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

You can find the codepoints for most arrows in the below wikipedia article (or just copy them directly)

- [Arrows by Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#Arrows_by_Unicode_block)
- [Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode#Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Arrows_block)

## 4. Alt+Numpad

By default it'll only work for codepoints smaller than 256, hence you can just type a few arrows like [Matt Smith's answer above](https://superuser.com/a/1067318/241386).

To type codepoints above 255 you need to use **hex numpad** by setting [`EnableHexNumpad`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows) to 1 in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method`. After that to type `↗` like above you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+2197</kbd>

Again you can find hundreds of arrows in my linked Wikipedia articles above

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to *Insert > Symbol* every time, you can right click *Symbol* and add it to the quick access toolbar (the blue bar up on top).

Once up there, it's two quick clicks versus three, or several presses with the Alt-codes

But that's not all...

If you then hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it shows you the hotkeys for all you've placed up there.

So for me:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> brings up the recent symbols box, then I navigate with <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select.

It may be about as many key strokes as Alt-codes but it's easier.
The only problem/benefit is they will change order as you use them, if you hate that then making macros for the arrows Alt-codes would be another way.
Your question suggests you know how to get symbols into the recent symbols box so I won't cover that.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also go Insert > Symbol > More Symbols > Font = Times new Roman > Subset = Arrows

Comment: .. as noted by OP in the question